# iphones bluetooth sharing possible?

Tags: apple-id, iphone

Its heard from century that iphone has bluetooth,but why we cant share anything over bluetooth,but infact we can connect bluetooth speaker and play some music.

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/70387

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- It's only between Apple devices, for iPhones, you can share together by AirDrop application.
- You can not share data over BT between PC & iPhone.
- Please view this for more information [Transfer files between your Mac and Bluetooth devices](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201820)

Answer (score 0):

If you are transferring between two apple devices, then you can use AirDrop. If you need to transfer data from a PC, then you can download the OneDrive app from the app store and use it.