# Bluetooth file transfer from Droid to Mac Mini

Tags: bluetooth, mac-mini, android

I followed the directions in:

[Bluetooth file transfer between Mac and android phone](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/251686/bluetooth-file-transfer-between-mac-and-android-phone) as well as the referenced How-to-Geek article (and I have rebooted several times too).

However after the pairing ritual is done, the transfer immediately fails, with a "connection failed" error.

I'm guessing it is an issue with the Mac Mini (or maybe Apple devices in general) as the Droid is able to send files via Bluetooth to other devices (but not any Apple ones).

I'm not sure how to even start troubleshooting.  Please help.